# check availability of 2 fields at number of times

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

in this page i want to check the Package and value_of_comp this two fields every time when i click add new row but i have facing problem is that it's checking only first row. please help me.

this is append part function

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    var i = 1;
    $('#add').click(function() {
        i++;
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><select class="form-control" id="' + i +
            '" name="Name_of_comp[]"><option value="">Select</option><option value="Capacitor">Capacitor</option><option value="Resistors">Resistors</option><option value="IC">IC</option><option value="Crystals">Crystals</option><option value="Transister">Transister</option><option value="Diodes">Diodes</option><option value="Sensor">Sensor</option><option value="Controller and processors">Controller & processors</option><option value="Connectors">Connectors</option><option value="Terminal Blocks">Terminal Blocks</option><option value="Inductors">Inductors</option><option value="Transformers">Transformers</option><option value="Line filters">Line filters</option><option value="Fuses & PTC">Fuses & PTC </option><option value="Switches and buttons">Switches and buttons</option><option value="Display">Display</option><option value="PCB">PCB</option></select></td><td><select class="form-control select1" id="' +
            i +
            '" name="Package[]"><option value="" class="p2">Select</option><option value="1206" class="p2">1206</option><option value="0805" class="p2">0805</option><option value="0402" class="p2">0402</option><option value="0603" class="p2">0603</option><option value="DIP" class="p2">DIP</option><option value="SOP" class="p2">SOP</option><option value="SSOP" class="p2">SSOP</option><option value="TSOP" class="p2">TSOP</option><option value="QTP" class="p2">QTP</option><option value="TQFP" class="p2">TQFP</option><option value="LQFP" class="p2">LQFP</option><option value="SOJ" class="p2">SOJ</option><option value="FLGA" class="p2">FLGA</option><option value="BGA/FBGA" class="p2">BGA/FBGA</option><option value="QFJ (PLCC)" class="p2">QFJ (PLCC)</option><option value="Wafer Level CSP (W-CSP)" class="p2">Wafer Level CSP (W-CSP)</option></select></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control name_list" name="Value_of_comp[]" id="' +
            i +
            '" placeholder="Enter Value"  onBlur="checkAvailability()"/></td><td><input type="text" name="Qty[]" id="' +
            i +
            '" placeholder="Enter your QTY" class="form-control " /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' +
            i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Remove</button></td></tr>');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
    });
    $('#addstock').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "login.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: $('#add_name').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
               // alert(data);
                $('#add_name')[0].reset();
                
            }
        });
    });
});





function checkAvailability() {

    var pck=$(".select1").val();
    var value1=$(".name_list").val();

    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "availibility.php",
        data: {
            pck:pck,
        value1:value1
        },                 
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#availability-status").html(data);
            $("#loaderIcon").hide();
        },
        error: function() {}
    });
}

//'Value_of_comp=' + $(".name_list").val(),


</script>
```

Comment: front end  <td><select class="form-control select1"  name="Package[]">
                                    <option value="" class="p2">Select</option>
                                    <option value="1206" class="p2">1206</option>
                                    <option value="0805" class="p2">0805</option>
                                    <option value="0402" class="p2">0402</option>

Comment: <td><input type="text" name="Value_of_comp[]" placeholder="Enter Value"
                                    class="form-control name_list" onBlur="checkAvailability()" /></td>

Comment: I strongly recommend to delegate from the table and not have inline event handlers

Comment: Where is `$('#addstock')`

Comment: <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button>
                    <input type="button" name="addstock" id="addstock" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />

Comment: Please click edit, then the `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]. Please do NOT post code or HTML in comments. Please update the QUESTION

Answer (score 0):

```
var pck=$(".select1").val();
var value1=$(".name_list").val();
```

will always only check the first occurrence of whatever fits the selector

Also delegate.

Here is a better script

I recommend cloning the first row since the IDs are not used at al
You had id="i" on many elements

```js
$(function() {
  $('#add').click(function() {
    const $row = $('#dynamic_field tr').first().clone(true);
    $row.find(":input").val(""); // empty the fields
    $('#dynamic_field').append($row);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  });
  $('#addstock').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "login.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: $('#add_name').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        // alert(data);
        $('#add_name')[0].reset();

      }
    });
  });
  $(".name_list").on("blur", function() {
    const $parent = $(this).closest("tr");
    const pck = $(".select1", $parent).val();
    const value1 = $(this).val();

    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    $.ajax({
      url: "availibility.php",
      data: {
        pck: pck,
        value1: value1
      },
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#availability-status").html(data);
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
      },
      error: function() {}
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button> <input type="button" name="addstock" id="addstock" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="dynamic_field">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="Name_of_comp[]">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="Capacitor">Capacitor</option>
          <option value="Resistors">Resistors</option>
          <option value="IC">IC</option>
          <option value="Crystals">Crystals</option>
          <option value="Transister">Transister</option>
          <option value="Diodes">Diodes</option>
          <option value="Sensor">Sensor</option>
          <option value="Controller and processors">Controller & processors</option>
          <option value="Connectors">Connectors</option>
          <option value="Terminal Blocks">Terminal Blocks</option>
          <option value="Inductors">Inductors</option>
          <option value="Transformers">Transformers</option>
          <option value="Line filters">Line filters</option>
          <option value="Fuses & PTC">Fuses & PTC </option>
          <option value="Switches and buttons">Switches and buttons</option>
          <option value="Display">Display</option>
          <option value="PCB">PCB</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control select1" name="Package[]">
          <option value="" class="p2">Select</option>
          <option value="1206" class="p2">1206</option>
          <option value="0805" class="p2">0805</option>
          <option value="0402" class="p2">0402</option>
          <option value="0603" class="p2">0603</option>
          <option value="DIP" class="p2">DIP</option>
          <option value="SOP" class="p2">SOP</option>
          <option value="SSOP" class="p2">SSOP</option>
          <option value="TSOP" class="p2">TSOP</option>
          <option value="QTP" class="p2">QTP</option>
          <option value="TQFP" class="p2">TQFP</option>
          <option value="LQFP" class="p2">LQFP</option>
          <option value="SOJ" class="p2">SOJ</option>
          <option value="FLGA" class="p2">FLGA</option>
          <option value="BGA/FBGA" class="p2">BGA/FBGA</option>
          <option value="QFJ (PLCC)" class="p2">QFJ (PLCC)</option>
          <option value="Wafer Level CSP (W-CSP)" class="p2">Wafer Level CSP (W-CSP)</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control name_list" name="Value_of_comp[]" placeholder="Enter Value" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Qty[]" placeholder="Enter your QTY" class="form-control " /></td>
      <td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: awesome Sir thank you so much its working perfectly.......